# TFS 13 Code Review Request

Tags: .net, tfs

I can't find any **Code Review Request** in tfs13 the only thing i can find everywhere is **Review** not the Code Review  . Please let me know where to find it.

Answer (score 3):

The code Review can be initiated from Team Explorer --> My Work --> In Progress Work, as shown in the image below, by clicking the Request Review link

Code review is only available in Premium or Higher Versions of TFS

[image: Request Code Review]

Comment: Please show me how to find My work in Team Explorer.I could only find Team Explorer --> Work Items

Comment: Do you have premium or higher?

Comment: You need Premium or higher to participate in Code Reviews. Premium is the version of VS targeted at teams.